# Task is not applying on Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

Please help me about how to register task on celery.

Error log is:

```
[2018-06-21 23:23:20,288: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'projects.tasks.hoge'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[2, true], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (84b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 561, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'project.tasks.hoge'
```

It worked fine on different environment and same source code.

Does anyone know why this occured?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your task, the command you're using to start your Celery workers, and the file with your Celery app (e.g., `app = Celery(...)`)?

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar

Task is on `app.tasks.py` in django application.
Celery is daemonized and start command is `/etc/init.d/celeryd start` .

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#init-script-celeryd

Comment: Ok, what does your `/etc/default/celeryd` look like? Specifically, the values of `CELERYD_CHDIR` and `CELERY_APP`. Also, do you have a `app = Celery(...)` line in your `app/tasks.py` file?